# How to filter a dataTable in dc.js without affecting other dimensions

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

So for a while I had struggled with how to filter a dataTable in dc.js without affecting other dimensions. This seems counter-intuitive, as it goes against what crossfilter(the data filter behind dc.js) does best, but I'll explain why this can be relevant.

Suppose I have a dataset of peoples name age and gender. In one of my datatables, I only want to display males; using one crossfilter, I would be forced to filter all my other datatables by males.

Suppose I also have a pie chart that lists the first letter of each person's name, and I want to be able to filter on the 'M's. I have a table for males, and a table for females. I don't want these tables to affect the distribution of the pie chart, but I want to be able to click on the pie chart and have it filter the dc.js datatables. More or a less a one way filter.

What is the way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

dc.js datatables accept crossfilter dimensions. I got around the problem by extending the dimension as follows.

```
function preFilter(dim,okey,oval){

    return{

        top:function(x){
            var a1 = dim.top(x).filter(function(v){
                return v[okey] === oval;
            });
            return a1;
        }
    };
}
```

This worked well for me, I hope it can help others.

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't figure out how these ``x1``, ``x2``, ... ``x10``, relate to the question. You had very a very simple example there, and I suggest you show the solution to exactly that. A textual explanation would be nice as well.

Comment: Specifically, I'm pretty sure all you need is the 'top' property on your return object to do what you want to do.

Comment: I trimmed my answer. Thanks for the advice. If your display needs access to other dimension functions just add them after top.